# How to get the default interface and its inet address?

Tags: android, linux, sockets

"Default interface" refers to ppp0:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 wlp3s0
172.30.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 wlp3s0
```

Which one is used  by default when I access WAN instead of LAN.
I need to run it on Android,so I can't use `getifaddrs`,because `ifaddrs.h` is **NOT** in the Android NDK.

Comment: [An implementation of getifaddrs() for Android](https://github.com/morristech/android-ifaddrs)

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, I don't know if an interface can be marked as "default", but there are plenty way to retrieve interface list without getifaddrs.

You can execute "ip link show" command and parse the result (or "ifconfig").
you can go to "/sys/class/net" where each directory reprensent an interface (and there is file under those directory that can help you).

I don't know if Android work like Debian, and I recommand you to find a way through Android NDK or system command (like "ip" or "ifconfig") because directory like /net or /proc are subject to change between different OS version (even if it's not really common, I can't recall to have see that).